# Showing a sequence space is totally bounded

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am trying to show that $X= \{(x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}:x_n\in [0,1]\space\forall \space n\}$ with the metric $d(x,y) = \sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{|x_k−y_k|}{2^k}$ is totally bounded.

To show that it is totally bounded, I think that for any $\epsilon >0$ (where WLOG I can consider consider $\epsilon=2^{-n}$), I have to find finitely many sequences $\{ x_1,...,x_{n_\epsilon}\}$ such $\{ B(x_i,\epsilon): i\in \{1,...,n_\epsilon\}\}$ covers X, but I haven't made much progress with this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$ arbitrary. Then there exists an $n\in\mathbb N$, such that
$$
\varepsilon>\frac{1}{2^n}.
$$
Consider now $S$ the finite set of all the elements $\boldsymbol{x}\in X$, of the form $\boldsymbol{x}=(x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1},0,0,\ldots)$, where
$$
x_j\in\left\{
\frac{k}{2^{n+1}}: k=0,1,2,\ldots,2^{n+1}
\right\}.
$$
Then, for every $\boldsymbol{y}=(y_1,\ldots,y_n,\ldots)\in X$, there exists a  $\boldsymbol{x}\in S$, such that
$$
|x_j-y_j|<\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}, \quad j=1,\ldots,n+1,
$$
and hence
$$
d(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{y})<\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\cdot\frac{1}{2^j}+\sum_{j=n+2}^{\infty} 
\frac{|y_j|}{2^j}<\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2^n}<\varepsilon
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \boldsymbol{y}\in B(\boldsymbol{x},\varepsilon).
$$
Hence
$$
X\subset \bigcup_{x\in S}B(x,\varepsilon).
$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Notice that for any $n\in\Bbb N$ and $x,y\in X$,

$$\sum_{k>n}\frac{|x_k-y_k|}{2^k}\le\sum_{k>n}\frac1{2^k}=\frac1{2^n}\,,$$

so

$$d(x,y)\le\frac1{2^n}+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{|x_k-y_k|}{2^k}\,.$$

If you knew that $$\frac{|x_k-y_k|}{2^k}<\frac1{n2^n}\tag{1}$$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$, you could conclude that $$d(x,y)<\frac1{2^{n-1}}$$ no matter what $x_k$ and $y_k$ are when $k>n$. Find a finite subset $F$ of $[0,1]^n$ such that for each $\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle\in[0,1]^n$ there is a $\langle y_1,\ldots,y_n\rangle\in F$ such that $(1)$ holds, and use it to get what you need for $\epsilon=\frac1{2^{n-1}}$.